# What is the compatible .NET Framework for ADF Custom .NET Activity?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, .net-framework-version, azure-batch

Actually I am developing a .NET tool for ADF custom .NET activity. The tool is running fine if the .NET framework is 4.5 or 4.5.2. But it is not running if I switch the framework version to 4.6. It is not even writing log in adfjobs folder. But it creates an empty stdout.txt file. Which means it's not supporting the v4.6? But actually I need the tool in v4.6 to support my further development. Should I have to do something with the batch account? 
Storage Type: Azure Lake Storage Gen 2.

Answer (score 1):

In ADF v2, custom activity runs in an Azure Batch pool. That pool has a server defined (ex: Windows Server 2016, 2019, etc). That server/vm level will determine what version of .NET is installed. You may need to create a new pool with a more up to date server version.